# RxJS: Change throttleTime after X emissions

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm building an RxJS slideshow where, if user holds the right arrow key, I want to navigate to the next tile at every 500 ms. I'm using `throttleTime` like below:

```
const forwardNavigation$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
    filter(event => event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.arrowRight),
    throttleTime(500)
);
```

What I would like to do now is to reduce the throttleTime to 100ms after I have navigated to the 5th tile without releasing the arrow key.

Is that possible, how would one go about implementing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a more declarative approach using only Observables, the following will work as well:

```
const source$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
  filter((event: KeyboardEvent) => event.code === "ArrowRight")
);
const slow$ = source$.pipe(throttleTime(500), take(5));
const fast$ = source$.pipe(throttleTime(100));

const forwardNavigation$ = concat(slow$, fast$);
// subscribe to forwardNavigation$ and execute navigation code
```

What this does is create two Observables from the keyboard events, with different throttleTimes.  It then uses `concat` to merge the results of both, which will ignore the second until the first completes.  Adding `take(5)` to the first observable means it completes after 5 emissions, at which point the `fast$` Observable takes over.

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-57967740?file=index.ts).

Comment: Thanks, that's precisely what I was looking for! Being a beginner in RxJs I couldn't even imagine how to solve this problem, your code and explanation gave me great insights into it!

Comment: By the way, since you mention you are new to rxjs, this pattern of splitting a source Observable, doing different operations on each “branch” and then merging the results is one I have used over and over.  [Here](https://rangle.io/blog/rxjs-where-is-the-if-else-operator/) is a good article explaining this pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `throttle` operator and return appropriate `interval` observable instead. Refer to the following example:

```js
import {fromEvent, interval} from 'rxjs';
import {filter, throttle} from 'rxjs/operators';

let iteration = 1;

const forwardNavigation$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
    filter(event => event.keyCode === 13),
    throttle(() => iteration++ % 5 === 0 ? interval(100) : interval(500))
);

forwardNavigation$.subscribe(console.log)
```

A working demo can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-z5agrx). Observe the console while pressing the `Enter` key.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful! I am just wondering, is it possible to avoid the global var `iteration`?

Comment: `iteration` here essentially points to the number of current slide, and `5` is the total number of slides. If you can devise those with another set of variables, it should also work.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here's the final code based on @dmcgrandle answer:

```
import { fromEvent, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, throttleTime, take, skip, startWith, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const keyboardRightKey$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
    filter(e => e.keyCode === 39)
);

fromEvent(document, 'keyup').pipe(
    startWith(true),
    switchMap(() => concat(
      keyboardRightKey$.pipe(throttleTime(500), take(5)),
      keyboardRightKey$.pipe(throttleTime(100), skip(1))
    ))
);
```

I added another bit to reset the stream on every `keyup` and then used [RxVIZ to create a visualization](https://rxviz.com/v/WJxG0PPO) of it.
[image]

Comment: Lots of ways to skin this cat.  Here's another using higher-order Observables: `of(
  source$.pipe(throttleTime(500), take(5)),
  source$.pipe(throttleTime(100))
).pipe(concatAll())`.  StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-57967740-2?file=index.ts)